# Is there a way to tell what Carrier Thread a Virtual Thread is running on?

Tags: java, multithreading, virtual-threads, project-loom

I am playing around with Project Loom for the first time and I have some code

```
try (var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()) {
    IntStream.range(0, 16).forEach(i -> {
        System.out.println("i = " + i + ", Thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread());
        executor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("Thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread());
        });
    });
}
```

with output like

```
Thread ID = VirtualThread[#37]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
Thread ID = VirtualThread[#33]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
i = 9, Thread ID = Thread[#1,main,5,main]
Thread ID = VirtualThread[#43]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
Thread ID = VirtualThread[#46]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
i = 10, Thread ID = Thread[#1,main,5,main]
i = 11, Thread ID = Thread[#1,main,5,main]
```

Is there a way I can tell what Carrier Thread each Virtual Thread is running on?

Does `ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11` represent a particular Carrier (Platform) Thread, or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this suffix is the name of the current carrier thread.

When I use the following code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Set<String> threadStrings = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    try(var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
        executor.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(16,
            () -> threadStrings.add(Thread.currentThread().toString())));
    }
    System.out.println("\tSimple Run");
    threadStrings.stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);

    threadStrings.clear();

    try(var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
        executor.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(16, () -> {
            threadStrings.add(Thread.currentThread().toString());
            Thread.sleep(100);
            return threadStrings.add(Thread.currentThread().toString());
        }));
    }
    System.out.println("\tWith wait");
    threadStrings.stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```

It prints

```
        Simple Run
VirtualThread[#15]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#17]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
VirtualThread[#18]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
VirtualThread[#19]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#20]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#21]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#22]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#23]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#24]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#25]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#26]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#27]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#28]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#29]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#30]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#31]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
        With wait
VirtualThread[#36]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
VirtualThread[#37]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
VirtualThread[#37]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#38]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
VirtualThread[#38]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#39]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#39]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#40]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
VirtualThread[#40]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#41]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
VirtualThread[#41]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#42]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7
VirtualThread[#42]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#43]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
VirtualThread[#43]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#44]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#44]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#45]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
VirtualThread[#45]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
VirtualThread[#46]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
VirtualThread[#46]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#47]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
VirtualThread[#49]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
VirtualThread[#49]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
VirtualThread[#50]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
VirtualThread[#50]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
VirtualThread[#51]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
VirtualThread[#51]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
VirtualThread[#52]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
VirtualThread[#52]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
```

<sup>(results may vary)</sup>

demonstrating how the carrier thread might change when performing a `sleep`. But in the current snapshot (“build 18-loom+6-282”) it’s not possible to specify your own `Executor` anymore and there is no method for querying the virtual thread about the carrier thread it uses (other than the implicit hint via `toString()`). So, the management of the underlying host threads is mostly a black box in this version.

Keep in mind that this is an ongoing development. It’s not clear whether and how this will change.

Comment: Even when the virtual threads were [delivered](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444), there is still no method exposed to query the details of a carrier thread apart from the suffix inference.

Comment: Well ... yea ... but given the carrier thread can change at any time (depending on the implementation), it is hard to see how this information could be used reliably by an app.  I imagine that that by not exposing it, they would avoid a bunch specification concerns, and  user confusion related to the method.  Either way, it is what it is.